# How to filter the json by multiple key in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a super long json string like

```
json= [{'2':[{'xxx':'xxxx'},...{'yyy':'yy'}]},{'65':[{'xxx':'xxxx'},...{'yyy':'yy'}]},{'980':....}]
```

if i wish to get all the key i will code is as:

```
json.keys()
```

then my output will be dict_keys(['2', '65', '980'])

And if i wish the selected key json, it will be **json['2']**

Now  my task require get some part of json string based on multiple key , that mean from json i wish to select those array string which the key is 2, 980

I have try **json['2';'980']** but it does not come to correct syntac, please help, any ideas?

Comment: Your `json` is a list of dictionaries not a dictionary. `json.keys()` should be an error.

Comment: for my side is not error, direct get key